# How to make a sql query in node.js with dynamic argument?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have searched in many forums for that question but without success. I'm a beginner with node.js and mysql, so I don't even know if this is possible maybe you have other offers for me :)

I want to write a SQL query dynamically for searching and comparing.

LIKE:

```
let username = req.body.username

const result = await db.query(
    `SELECT * FROM users 
     WHERE username = ?,
     [username]
);
```

But in my request, I get the attribute for search in the database and also the data to compare with.

```
let attribute = req.body.attribute
let data = req.body.data

const result = await db.query(
    `SELECT * FROM users 
     WHERE ${attribute} = ?,
     [data]
);

if(result) {
    //send result as response
}
```

Comment: ```const result = await db.query(
    `SELECT * FROM users 
     WHERE ? = ?,
     [attribute, data]
  );```give me an empty array ... []

Comment: The code you posted in the question should work.

Comment: You can't use a placeholder for the column name.

Comment: So I need to code every possibility?

Comment: You can use the template string as you did, along with a whitelist to protect against SQL injection.